# Explain the difference between ActionController#respond_to and ActionController::respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, respond-to

I've read the documentation, and it confuses me every time, just because it doesn't answer some basic things.  I realize the main purpose of the class method `::respond_to` (which is normally used at the top of the controller) is for use in conjunction with `respond_with`.  And the purpose of the instance method `#respond_to` (normally at the end of each action) is to provide different responses for different formats.

I also know that it's possible to consolidate the instance method version to look like the class method, but used inside an action, for conciseness, like this: `respond_to(:html)`.  The use case for this is another purpose of `#respond_to`, which is to refuse requests for unspecified formats. (I think it raises an UnspecifiedFormat exception)

Does the class method also have the same functionality?  For instance, if I have a controller that *only* responds to html, if I just put `respond_to(:html)` at the top of the file, can I expect it to refuse requests for other formats?  I've had problems with it doing that, so I don't know if I've been doing something wrong, or if it's just not supposed to work the same as the instance method in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally ran an experiment, and no, the class method `respond_to` does NOT refuse requests to unspecified formats like the instance method does.  Kind of a confusing disparity, but there you have it.  If you want to refuse requests for invalid formats (with a 406), you have to specify valid formats inside each action of each controller (using the instance method `respond_to`)